# Python Openpyxl/Pandas change font color and bold font based on condition in Excel and save

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Even though this question seems to have been answered, I fear some of the posts might be outdated, or openpyxl has deprecated this functionality.

I need to change some font formatting within an Excel file using Python based upon a certain condition. If in columns 'MIC' and 'B5BA' the cell == '2 Person Entry Error' change cell font color to Red and Bold the font. I followed the tutorial and other examples to a tee, but the font is not changing. I iterate through columns and rows to obtain cell coordinates, I compare the value within the cell, if cell value meets the condition change the font. The cell font is not changing in my saved file.

I posted code that will automatically write the excel workbook from a df, then read the Excel workbook. Has openpyxl deprecated this capability? Help is appreciated! Code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, colors
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

data = [
    [1, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-10', 'Monday', 'Lunch', '2 Person Entry Error', '2 Person Entry Error', None],
    [1, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-10', 'Monday', 'Dinner', '2 Person Entry Error', '2 Person Entry Error', None],
    [2, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-10', 'Monday', 'Dinner', 'John', None, None],
    [2, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-11', 'Tuesday', 'Lunch', 'Bob', 'Mackenzie ', None],
    [3, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-11', 'Tuesday', 'Dinner', '2 Person Entry Error', '2 Person Entry Error', None],
    [3, '2022-10-10', '2022-10-12', 'Wednesday', 'Lunch', '2 Person Entry Error', '2 Person Entry Error', None]
]
cols = ['Store', 'Start Date', 'Date', 'Day of Week', 'Shift', 'MIC', 'B5BA', 'Task']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df.to_excel('input.xlsx', index=False)

input_file_path = 'input.xlsx'
output_file_path = 'output.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(input_file_path)
ws = wb.active

col_start = 6
col_end = 7
row_start = 2
row_end = ws.max_row

for col_num in range(col_start, col_end + 1):
    col_letter = get_column_letter(col_num)
    for row_num in range(2, row_end + 1):
        # cell_coordinate = ws.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        cell_coordinate = ws[f'{col_letter}{row_num}']
        print(cell_coordinate, f'{col_letter}{row_num}')
        if cell_coordinate.value == '2 Person Entry Error':
            cell_coordinate = Font(color='FF0000', bold=True)

wb.save(output_file_path)
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any links to "examples" mentioned, it is impossible to judge if you are doing the *exact* same thing as they advertise. Either way, the fix should be as follows. Change:

```
            cell_coordinate = Font(color='FF0000', bold=True)
```

Into:

```
            cell_coordinate.font = Font(color='FF0000', bold=True)
```

See the [`documentation`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#cell-styles).

Result for `output.xlsx`:

[image: output]